How would a cube-moon orbit a Cube-World with uniform surface gravity?
A cube-world with uniform surface gravity has been made using extremely strong materials of varying densities, and is orbiting a star, rotating on a axis between two corners (like spinning a d6). Due to the odd density distribution of the planet (which is required for the uniform surface gravity), the gravitational field is cube-like near the surface of the planet.
Would the gravitational oddness of the planet affect things at Earth-Luna distances enough to prevent having a Luna-sized moon (also a uniform-surface-gravity cube) orbiting the planet? Would the uniform surface gravity (and odd density map) of the Luna-sized moon affect things?
If things would be affected, would it be enough to prevent having a moon at all, just make the orbit of the moon weird, or would it only be possible to have a farther/smaller moon, or one orbiting in a different path?

In a squarebit, not an orbit, presumably.

@gs You mean a squareit, or, even better, a cubeit, I take it?

@Joachim Cubits as a celestial mechanic is far better than cubits as an archaic measurement.

I'm not even going to try to work out the math, but the simple rules of thumb seem to me to be:

The basic rules of "mass" still apply. All the mass within a sphere, regardless the shape of that mass, can be modeled as a single point at the center of the distribution.

As the ratio of mass increases between the two objects, the stability of the orbit increases, until a disparity in size is reached that the smaller mass is simply pulled into the larger.

As the distance between the two objects increases, the stability of the orbit increases, until a distance is reached that will no longer hold the gravitational bond.


Consequently, my gut reaction is...
You may need to have a bit more distance between cube-earth and cube-luna, but yes, in a universe that permits cube celestial bodies, the orbit is believable.
I'm taking the science-fiction tag at its word, and thanks for using it. In the Real Universe (even assuming manufactured objects), time would reduce any material worth talking about to a spheroid. If you used a material that wouldn't believably reduce (e.g., neutron star material), you'd be dealing with objects so small that all the spheroid rules would apply anyway.
Having said all that, I could be wrong, being an engineer and not an astrophysicist, but that's my story and I'm sticking to it.

point 1 is not always true. See mascon on the Moon, and how they mess up with orbits around the Moon.

@L.Dutch Thanks for the reference to mascons. I believe point #1 as a generalization is still true (due primarily to point #3) and that the issue of mascons (see this article) simply supports my conclusion that the OP's idea is good to go.

The mass distribution will affect either body, but only to a small margin not enough to change the orbit's shape visibly
In fact, what we calculate as gravity force is actually an integral by volume of G*dm/dr^2, which is equal to G*M/r^2 if the gravitating mass is an uniform sphere. It's actually not exact for real-world planets, as they have more density on the inside, such discrepancies make some difference to actual gravity force on the planet, yet these are of second (IIRC) order of small compared to density difference in the planet's crust, which is actively used by geologists to find large cavities or ore deposits underground.
But, assuming your planet has the mass and side of about 1.0 Earth, and your cube-moon to have the same relation to our Moon, the Earth's visible angle from the Moon is about 2.0 degrees, this is below 5.0 degrees normally used as a margin of "sin(x)~=x" equation to fit, thus the model of a single gravitational mass in the mass center of cube-earth would still apply with enough precision to matter, and the orbit of your cubemoon would still be elliptical with low eccentricity. The same applies to Earth->Moon side.
There will be an issue on what side will your cube-moon face your cube-earth; I expect it to eventually get tidally locked with one vertex directed towards the cube-earth, because of the known effect that two rigidly connected masses orbiting a celestial body eventually align on the orbit so that the line connecting them points towards the mass center of that body. Here we (as a first approximation) have 8 masses in your cube-moon, the most difference of gravity forces towards the cube-earth will be achieved in that alignment. So, expect your cube-earth inhabitants to see a hexagon in orbit, not a cube.
